# How could I check if a value in an array begins with a certain letter?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a program in which a user picks a letter. The program should then search through a list and count how many names start with the letter the user chose.

This is what I've got so far:

```
nameslist = ["bob", "phil", "james"]

letter = input("Pick a letter.")
letter = letter.lower()

wordcount = 0

for I in range(len(nameslist)-1):
   if list[I].startswith(letter):
      wordcount = wordcount+1
      print(list[I])
```

I was led to believe that `startswith` would help me but it doesn't work.

Comment: `range(x)` returns a generator of values 0 to x-1 making it perfect for list indexes. The `-1` in `range(len(nameslist)-1)` is what breaks it.

Comment: Your code is actually almost right. Just remove the `-1` in `range` and replace `list` with `nameslist`

Comment: You could use len([name for name in names if name.startswith(letter)])

Comment: `list` is built in python, dont use `list` as variable names

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
names = ["bob","phil","james"]

letter = input("Pick a letter.")
letter = letter.lower()
count = 0   

for name in names:
    if name.startswith(letter):
        print(name)
        count += 1
```

This iterates over each `name` in `names` and uses the `startswith()` method to check whether `name` begins with `letter`. If `name` begins with `letter`, it prints `name`. It also counts the number of `name` in `names` that begin with `letter` using the `count` variable.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep your current code all you need to do is fix some typos. Here is the correct code with comments showing what I changed:

```
nameslist=["bob","phil","james"]

letter=input("Pick a letter.")
letter=letter.lower()

wordcount=0

for I in range(len(nameslist)):  # you dont need the -1 at the end of this
   if nameslist[I].startswith(letter): # you need to change list to nameslist
      wordcount=wordcount+1
      print(nameslist[I])  # you need to change list to nameslist
```